# Performing rawQuery and place resulting value for each row in database

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

So currently on add to my database, I perform this select statement get the result and add it to a separate column in my database, and it looks as follows:

```
public void addGasLog(GasLog gasLog){
        // Get reference to writable DB
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // Create ContentValues to add key "column"/value
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        //...

        Cursor cursor = getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("select (" + gasLog.getOdometer() + " - y.odometer) / " + gasLog.getGallons() + " as mpg from gasLog x, gasLog y where y.odometer = (select max(z.odometer) from gasLog z where z.odometer < " + gasLog.getOdometer() + ")", null);
        try {
              if (cursor.moveToFirst()) { 
                  mpg = cursor.getString(0);
              }
            } finally {
              cursor.close();
            }
        values.put(KEY_MPG, mpg);

        Log.d("MySQLiteHelper", KEY_MPG);

        // Insert
        long gasLog_id = db.insert(TABLE_GASLOG, //table
                null, //nullColumnHack
                values); // key/value -> keys = column names/ values =


        db.close();
}
```

So this is good, it performs my calculation needed in the select statement and inserts the correct value in the mpg column for that row.

What I need is to be able to use this similar functionality, and perform it on each row in the database... so run that select statement on each row, and pass the value into the mpg column for each row it hits.

I know a few values will change, like `gasLog.getOdometer()` will need to instead get the value of the "odometer" column for that row and `gasLog.getGallons()` will need to be the value from the "gallons" column for that row.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:  I am looking to put the results from this question into a new method that I can run separately, which will go through each row on the database and update them all.

EDIT2:

This is the method I created which is now creating blank columns

```
public void updateMPG(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("select ('odometer' - y.odometer) / 'gallons' as mpg from gasLog x, gasLog y where y.odometer = (select max(z.odometer) from gasLog z where z.odometer < 'odometer')", null);
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        try {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (true) {
                mpg = cursor.getString(0);
                values.put(KEY_MPG, mpg);
                long gasLog_id = db.insert(TABLE_GASLOG, null, values);
                if (cursor.isLast())
                    break;
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
        db.close();

    }
```

EDIT3:
[image: database]

Comment: Just to make sure I got the question right, what you are saying is that you can do it for the first row but you need a solution to basically iterate the cursor through the rest of the rows?

Comment: Close, I can do this for the current row being added to the database, so addGasLog adds 1 new row, and for that row the data is correct.  I need a separate method that iterates through the rest of the rows, performing the same calculation and adding the results to their respective "mpg" column

Comment: Or, instead of saying "rest of the rows" i should say, i need it to iterate through ALL rows, performing the same calculation, so that I can call it at any point and update every value in the "mpg" column of the database, based off that statement

Comment: Ok.. I'll type out the code to move through all the rows (from the first to the last), then you can modify it depending on whether you need to do it in a method or so

Comment: In your table, there is a column KEY_MPG correct? When you run this query through debug, does mpg return a value? IF It does, then it should be put in the solution. Can you debug, place breakpoints and then see what you get? Unless the query returns nothing, this should be inserting something into TABLE_GASLOG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you would go through all the rows in the database and modify the mpg column value in the TABLE_GASLOG table.

```
Cursor cursor = getWritableDatabase().rawQuery("select (" + gasLog.getOdometer() + " - y.odometer) / " + gasLog.getGallons() + " as mpg from gasLog x, gasLog y where y.odometer = (select max(z.odometer) from gasLog z where z.odometer < " + gasLog.getOdometer() + ")", null);
try {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int key = 1;
    while (true) {
        mpg = cursor.getString(0);
        values.put(KEY_MPG, mpg);
        db.update(TABLE_GASLOG, values, "_id=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(key)});
        if (cursor.isLast())
            break;
        cursor.moveToNext();
        key++;
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
db.close();
```

This code will basically iterate over your entire result set and then extract the mpg value in each row and insert it into your TABLE_GASLOG database.

EDIT: This will add more rows to TABLE_GASLOG. From you comment, I understand that you need to update your row. In this case, instead of db.insert() method, please use:

```
update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

your where clause will depend on whatever your condition is.

Comment: So i was able to get this to sort of work.  It doesnt produce any errors, it just creates a bunch of blank rows in the database rather than updating the MPG for each existing row.

Comment: I have added an edit to my existing post which shows the method I created out of your work.

Comment: Can you please see my edited answer. From your question, I understood it as to read and write new rows.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the insert to update but im not sure I have it quite right...

long gasLog_id = db.update(TABLE_GASLOG, values, KEY_ID +" = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(KEY_ID) });

Comment: I need to see your table for this but your whereArgs seems wrong. My guess is you are trying to move to the immediate next row - in which case you need to increment KEY_ID by one. Do you have an index in TABLE_GASLOG? If yes, you could use that to mention that you are moving to the next row. One idea would be to keep a counter which keeps incrementing at the end of each iteration. Match this counter with the row where you are trying to insert.

Comment: Thank you. I had to step away and will try that as soon as i get a chance.  Thanks for all of your help

Comment: I have added an image of what my DB table looks like.

Comment: Done editing my answer. I have basically included a key counter which keeps incrementing at the end of each iteration to keep a count of which record the data should be entered to. But from this it looks like you are pulling and inserting the values into the same table - I'm not sure I understood what you are trying to do???

Comment: So my goal here is trying to calculate miles per gallon for each record in the database.  Right now, it correctly enters MPG data if each record is entered in order.  where it becomes a problem is when a user enters a record out of order.  If you look at my image above, record 1, 2, 3 all calculate MPG correctly.  when user enters record 4 which would theoretically come between 2 & 3 (based off odometer reading) it does not recalculate the new MPG for record 3

Comment: I think we are on the right track.  Right now it clears out the MPG column, i think its not getting data in the cursor or something.. Working with that trying to figure that out now.